# skaffold dev error: retrieving image timeout

Tags: docker, skaffold

Running **skaffold dev** gives this error:

```
listing files: parsing ONBUILD instructions: retrieving image "node:alpine": Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

I am using **skaffold version v1.37.2** and running it using latest **docker-desktop** kubernetes on **mac OS**.